# python workspace structuring

Tags: ros, catkin.workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently struggling to setup a python ros workspace..  I've been following this guide

http://duckietown.mit.edu/media/pdfs/1rpRisFoCYUm0XT78j-nAYidlh-cDtLCdEbIaBCnx9ew.pdf

and my src folder looks like this

```
src
├── CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
└── service
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── include
    │   └── service
    │       ├── __init.py__
    │       └── util.py
    ├── package.xml
    ├── setup.py
    └── src
        └── publisher.py
```

When i run rosrun service publisher.py i get the error message:

```
line 5, in <module>
    from service import util 
ImportError: cannot import name util
```

setup.py

```
## ! DO NOT MANUALLY INVOKE THIS setup.py, USE CATKIN INSTEAD
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup
# fetch values from package.xml
setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
packages=['service'],
package_dir={'': 'include'},
)
setup(**setup_args)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248572/python-workspace-structuring/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2016-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yeah.. I am blind.

```
__init.py__ != __init__.py
```

---

Originally posted by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) with karma: 156 on 2016-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0